# Como embutir exe em Projeto Delphi?

Tags: delphi

### Cenário:

Possuo um sistema desenvolvido em Delphi 5 e outro em Delphi EX8.
No Delphi 5 chamo o executável do EX8, até ai tudo bem, por que seria apenas um programa a mais para o usuário baixar e deixar na pasta bin,mas terei que criar 2 módulos novos que serão chamados da mesma forma, e isto iria gerar muitos arquivos para baixar.

Existe uma solução que fizesse a união deles?

### Nota:

> Não posso migrar o Projeto Delphi 5 para EX8.

---

Comment: Só pra saber se eu entendi perfeitamente, você quer usar o programa feito em Delphi 5 como um recurso a ser chamado pelo programa feito em Delphi XE8?

Comment: Não vi muito sentido, mas você pode incluir como recurso. Não é aconselhável neste caso, mas pode incluir. No Delphi 7 tinha uma instrução de compilação. Acho que era {$R 'nome-do-arquivo'}, assim como o Delphi já incluía os DFM's no recurso (existe um comando desse em cada form).

Comment: @DarkHyudrA pelo contrario, quero embutir um EX8 em um 5

Comment: O buraco é bem fundo, e tem um código que um carinha gringo fez uma vez, mas não posso te prometer que ele funciona em Delphi 5. Nessa pergunta do SO, na primeira resposta tem o link pra Unit utilizada e mais detalhes de como usar ela: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395493/execute-an-exe-file-from-resource-into-memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe sim, o procedimento é simples de fazer!

Você vai usar o `BRCC32` que é responsável também por gerar os Recursos para o Delphi!

Vamos criar um teste!

- 1 - Crie e salve um projeto com apenas 1 botão no formulário.
- 2 - Na pasta onde foi salvo os fontes do projeto, copie para a mesma
  o arquivo `BRCC32.EXE` que esta na pasta Bin de instalação do Delphi (eu sempre prefiro copiar).
- 3 - Adicione nessa pasta também um arquivo executável de sua escolha!

  - 3.1 - Crie um arquivo de texto (qualquer nome) com a seguinte estrutura (sem o cabeçalho explicativo) na pasta do projeto salvo
    anteriormente.
    Nome do Recurso - Identificador - Caminho do Arquivo que será anexado
    ArquivoTeste EXEs "caminho completo da pasta do projeto\nome do
    arquivo e sua extensão" (3 paramentos, o ultimo deve estar em aspas
    duplas)
  - 3.2 - Troque a extensão desse arquivo de `.txt` para `.rc`
- 4 - Temos tudo pronto para criar nosso arquivo de recurso!

  - 4.1 - No Executar do windows: 'Caminho da pasta' '\brcc32' 'nome do arquivo criado no 3.1 com extensão' (não use as aspas ex:
    `c:\temp\teste\brcc32 nome_desejado.rc`)
  - 4.2 - Observe que na pasta do projeto foi criado um novo arquivo com o mesmo nome do `.rc` com a extensão `.res`
- 5 - Abra o projeto e abaixo de **{$R *.DFM}** adicione **{$R nome do
  arquivo res com extensão}**
- 6 - No evento click do botão vamos efetuar a Extração do executável
  para poder ser usado pelo sistema.

---

```
procedure frmTeste.btnIniciarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Stream: TResourceStream;
begin                                        
  Stream := TResourceStream.Create(hInstance, 'ArquivoTeste', 'EXEs'); //Nome do recurso criado e Tipo 
  try
    Stream.SaveToFile('caminho_completo\ArquivoTeste.exe'); //ex: c:\temp\teste\ArquivoTeste.exe
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

- 7 - Compile o projeto, para certificar que deu tudo certo, apague os
  arquivos RC, RES, e o executável que foi anexado!

  - 7.1 - Execute a aplicação e teste!

---

Alguns recursos podem ser usados na memória, não precisando fazer a extração!
Esse roteiro acabei de montar, se tiver algo errado ou procedimento que falhou me avise que eu faço a correção!

Comment: `+1`, que receita de bolo hein ? Vou testar a sua solução!

Comment: kkkkk eu prefiro responder assim! Tem coisas que não gosto deixar margens pra duvidas!

Comment: Era isso mesmo, deu certo aqui obrigado!